# Resize particular section of collage as in Layout App (Photo Collage App)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, resize

I am creating a Photo Collage App. I want to resize any selected section of collage as in [Layout App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/layout-from-instagram/id967351793)

[The original layout when images are selected for a collage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDRjM.png)

[Layout after resizing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi2tv.jpg)

**Note:** I am not using auto layout

I used the below code to add scroll views

```
func addScrolls(index: Int) {
    if let templatesArray = self.templates?.templates?[index - 1].scrolls {
        //templatesArray contains the array of dictionary that contains coordinates of the frame
        //If I get coordinates as [(x:0, y:0, width: 160, height: 160), (x:160, y:0, width: 160, height: 160), (x:0, y:160, width: 160, height: 160), (x:160, y:160, width: 160, height: 160)] from the templatesArray variable
        for dic in templatesArray {
            guard let  x = dic.x else { return }
            guard let y = dic.y else { return }
            guard let width = dic.width else { return }
            guard let height = dic.height else { return }
            let frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
            let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: frame)
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
            self.superFrame.addSubview(scrollView)
            //superFrame has the frame (0,0,320,320)
            let frm = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: scrollView.contentSize)
            let imgView = UIImageView(frame: frm)
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: self.imgArr[index])
            scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
        }
    }
}
```

[My collage layout after adding the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOzu9.jpg)

When a particular image is tapped, I've added the resize buttons as in below screenshot

[Resize buttons added when the image is tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc9NW.jpg)

How can I achieve the resizing functionality in the collage layout?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be better to use `UICollectionView` for displaying images instead of nested scroll views

Comment: @bazyl87 Thank for the response! I tried to use UICollectionView, but in my case, I need to scroll image inside its superview, so I used UIScrollView, instead of UICollectionView

Comment: I think you need to update all image view frames when you change the layout

Comment: @bazyl87 Yes, I thought of this, but for that, I need to find out all the affected ScrollViews of the selected ScrollView, because I am not using auto layout.

Comment: have you done this application?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad I haven't done the resizing part, the collage was completed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @KrimaShah I am building the same kind of application and the problem I am facing is that I don't know what is the best approach. firstly I did it with the collection view then I face scalability issues now I am doing it with the combination of uibazierPath, CAShapeLayer and CALayer with the static height of frame can you help me with that
Thankyou

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad I referred to this JSON file https://github.com/Belinskaya/Collage/blob/master/collage_templates.txt and I used UIBazierPath for making my collages, you are on right path, just refer to this JSON.